# I want to fetch data between two dates but not getting the result with last date including I am writing postgres query like

Tags: java, postgresql

```
select * , s.schema_name, s.version 
from credential c, 
     schema s 
where c.schema_id = s.schema_id 
  and c.updated_at BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-05-02' 
  and c.status = 'PROPOSAL_RECEIVED' 
  and c.deleted = false.
```

In my DB i have data for both the dates but not getting data for 02-05-2022.
Please help thanks...

Comment: Can you give your table sample? Or some online db fiddle?

Comment: What exactly is the data type of your `updated_at` column?

Answer (score 1):

When working with time intervals (as with other intervals), half-open intervals offer clarity and convenience. For example, the length of the interval is simply the difference between the upper and lower bounds (you don't have to "plus one" like you do with inclusive bounds). And, it's simple to create adjacent intervals, including every point in just one interval.

The inclusive, closed-interval BETWEEN operator fails miserably here. I recommend using half-open constraints like this:

```sql
...
AND c.updated_at >= '2022-05-01' AND c.updated_at < '2022-05-03'
...
```

Note that the upper bound is May 3 instead of May 2, and the upper bound operator is strictly less-than rather than less-than-or-equal.

Now, no matter the precision of your timestamps, every instant of May 1–2 will be included, while records stamped 00:00:00 will never be included in two result sets. This avoids fragile workarounds like subtracting one second (or one <s>millisecond</s> microsecond, …).

As a side-effect, this eliminates the problem caused by inferring 00:00:00 as the missing time-of-day component in your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If column "updated_at" were of type "date", then your query would work as written.

But if it is of type timestamp (with or without tz) then the endpoint is inclusive but it includes only the first millisecond of the specified day, not the entirety of that day.

If you only want dates, then use the "date" type.